# Can I use PHP to save only the visible elements of the output as a new file?

Tags: php, html, save, visible

I've got a php file that takes an xml file (generated by an outside source) and reformats it with CSS & HTML. A number of the XML tags are things I don't want to see in the final version, so I have them hidden. The end result is something like this:

```
<html>
<div style="display: none">
    content i don't want to see
</div>

content I do want to see.

</html>
```

Is there a way I can take the resulting html file as it's displayed in the browser window,

```
content I do want to see.
```

…and save that as a text file? I want it to ignore all the hidden `<div>` tags and only save what can otherwise be selected and copied by the user.

I've looked around for an answer to this but I'm not even really sure what I'm looking for or how to search it.

I've also tried this:

```
ob_start();
file_put_contents('filename.htm', ob_get_contents());
ob_end_flush();
```

… but that's doesn't solve it. I have a number of tags in the outputted test (`&gt;` etc) that need to be saves as they are displayed, and `ob_get_contents()` takes the page's source code, not the displayed version.

This matters because the outputted page is also PHP that has been generated based on other factors, so I need to use html unicode values to keep the $ signs and quotes from messing up the source PHP.

I hope that was clear. Thanks in advance for any help or suggestions.

Comment: There are many ways that things may or may not be visible in a browser. What you essentially want is to have the entire site interpreted by a complete browser engine and retrieve the version "as seen by a human" afterwards. Honestly, there must be a better solution to solve whatever you're trying to solve.

Comment: Not as "seen by a human" per se, but more as seen as it would be copied and pasted into Notepad.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to strip out the unneeded part manually, using a RegEx something, which maybe like:

```
$content_raw = ob_get_contents();
$content_stripped = preg_replace($content_raw, '<div style="display: none">[^<>]*</div>', '');
file_put_contents('filename.htm', $content_stripped);
```

Comment: `ereg_replace`? That's been deprecated in favour of the `preg_*` variants.

Comment: true. please use preg_replace instead.

Comment: That helps quite a bit, but what about converting the `$#34;` values as they would be displayed without messing with the PHP that writes them?